# Why the ae1's `Link` is `down` but its indicator is light?

Tags: juniper, juniper-ex

In my Juniper EX4300 I created a `ae1`

I added `xe-0/2/3` and `xe-1/2/3` to `ae1`,

```
xe-0/2/3 {
    ether-options {
        802.3ad ae1;
    }
}
xe-1/2/3 {
    ether-options {
        802.3ad ae1;
    }
}
```

and `ae1` is a trunk port.

```
ae1 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            interface-mode trunk;
            vlan {
                members all;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it connect to other switch(HUAWEI 5720's Eth-Trunk 1[Gig-0/0/1 + Gig-1/0/1]), and the indicator is light.

but why the `Link` is `down`?

When I `show interface terse`:

```
......
ae1.0   up  down ether-switch
......
```

My question are:

1. why the ae1.0's Link status is down?
2. and when I `show interfaces terse` there do not have `xe-0/2/3` and `xe-1/2/3`, and do not list all other `xe-*` interfaces. why?

Comment: Did you set the linkmode to lacp? set interface ae1 aggregated-ether-options lacp active

Comment: @244boy. You have to check 'LACP' mode on both sides of trunk. As per your configuration , LACP mode of ae1 interface is 'passive' , meaning it is listening for LACP PDUs from other side. In your case , other side must be configured to LACP active for bundle link to go up.You can also configure your bundle link in active mode. There is no harm in it.

Comment: aggregated-ether-options {
    lacp {
        active;
    }
}